# Install VM Virtual Box as Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, virtual-machine, virtualbox, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have VM Virtual Box running a Windows Phone emulator. How do I get Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition to use it to test a Windows Phone app?

Apparently one is supposed to use the Device Emulator Manager to register emulators and it ought to be accessible from the Tools menu but its not there.

Comment: the Phone Emulaters always require Hyper-V :(

Comment: Not according to this video... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1blKbQRR5g

Comment: please look at this horrible UX. You need a guest addon for WP which doesn't exist to get the VM working fine

Comment: Working fine with Virtual Box?